# Select ENTITY_ID where sum of USER_ID points is greater than the sum of every other USER_ID's points

Tags: sql, postgresql

I the following table

```
table edits
- user_id
- entity_id
- points: smallint
```

A user can have multiple rows for the same `entity_id`.

I want to return a list of entity_id's where the sum of `user: 1`'s points is greater than the sum of any other user's points for a particular entity. I'm guessing it's done with a `group by [user_id, entity_id]` and a `having sum(user_id: 1) >= sum(user_id)` but that's where my knowledge ends.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . Is this what you want?

```
select e.*
from edits e
where e.points < (select e2.points
                  from edits e2
                  where e2.entity_id = e.entity_id and e2.user_id = 1
                 ) and
      e.entity_id = ?;
```

Comment: Your answer made me realize I forgot a crucial detail which is that a user can have multiple rows in the edits table for the same entity_id.

Comment: @keslert . . . You should probably ask another question because that substantially changes the question.  Which value would you want to use?  The biggest, smallest, most common, average, sum?